# Slow Gradle build times after migration to Java 11

Tags: gradle, java-8, build, java-11

I have a large project with quite a few Gradle modules (around 90+) and we're seeing some strange build behaviour - especially after migrating to a Java 11 build (from Java 8).

Specifically our test execution times are... wonky.

Running the `test` target for the entire project this module takes 4min 55s to executes the tests.

Running the `test` target for a single module on its own it merely takes 1min 15s for the exact same tests with the same results.

Note: Before these both Gradle tests a clean on the entire project had been executed. These times are reproducible with minor time differences.

As a reference: running the tests for the module in IntelliJ I'm at 1min 18s.

I have played around with `maxParallelForks` and `forkEvery`, but I did not notice any significant changes.

I'm at a loss to what I could try and would appreciate any ideas and suggestions.

Comment: Were you able to get around this issues? I'm facing the same problem

Comment: I encountered this problem too on our project running on docker. I found out, that the cause was in specific JDK we've used (Open JDK 11). When I switched to Eclipse Temurin JDK 11, the problem was gone.